# Smtp Client C# Problem with Aruba PEC and with attachment

Tags: c#, smtpclient

this is my code:

```
try {
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.aruba.it", 25);
                        client.EnableSsl = true;
                        client.Timeout = 10000;
                        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("receiver@pec.it", "password");
                        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                        msg.To.Add("receiver@pec.it"); //Receiver
                        msg.From = new MailAddress("sender@pec.it"); //Sender
                        msg.Subject = "Object"; //Oggetto Mail
                        msg.Body = ""; //Corpo del testo
                        Attachment data = new Attachment(fileName);
                        msg.Attachments.Add(data);
                        client.Send(msg);
                        MessageBox.Show("Attachment send correctly");
                    }
                    catch (SmtpException ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException
                          ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
                    }
```

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work. I tried with gmail host and it works, so the code should work. The problem is smtp for sure but I couldn't find the right way to send it via pec aruba.
Another problem is the attachment. The name of attachment is the entire filename path and i want that is only the name of the file. How i can resolve this two problem?

Comment: I just resolve the problem with the name of attachment, but there is always the problem of smtp aruba

Comment: Look at the last answer here: https://forum.italia.it/t/invio-fatture-tramite-pec-aruba-e-net-c/8086/12

Comment: Don't work with the port and host of the last answer

Answer (score 1):

Use smtps.aruba.it instead smtp.aruba.it and port 587. It works for me ( I had same problem)